# getting null pointer exception when trying to print object

Tags: java, android

Below is the relevant code:

```
          WebPage obPage1 = new WebPage(null, null, 0);

          obPage1.setUrl(page1.substring(st + 4, en));

          System.out.println(obPage1.toString());
```

This is giving me a nullpointer exception any idea where im going wrong?

Comment: where are you seeing the null pointer?

Comment: the system.out.println is causing the exception

Comment: does your WebPage override the toString() method ?

Comment: nope I could try that thanks

Comment: check content of WebPage.toString() method. You are constructing WebPage objects with some null constructor params, so mostly those attributes will be used in toString resulting in nullpointer

Comment: look at your "toString()" function in your class or in your parent class

Answer (score 0):

Is WebPage a custom class you wrote?

Even if you didn't implement a toString method, it should still return valid string since it would be extend the Object's toString method

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The quickest way to determine what the code is doing is running it in debugger mode so you can whats being stored inside WebPage.

Also looks like from the example that you want toString to return the url of a page.  If thats the case, just make a getter for the url.